# Amazon Web Services - Using an existing EC2 instance as Beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to AWS, and I want to deploy a web application on an EC2 instance,

So far I've tried Elastic Beanstalk, but AWS always requires me to create a new Environment for the application instead of letting me choose an existing EC2 instance that I've created before. 
Actually my main purpose is to set a policy group that allow HTTPS access, and idk how to set it to the "Environment" instance.

Any help is greatly welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

That is not currently viable, as you'd need to set up an AMI based on your instance and use a custom AMI for beanstalk, and that is not a trivial task. If you need to run a custom environment in Elastic Beanstalk, using Docker would be much easier.

But none of that is required to set a security group allowing HTTPS, you can configure security groups and HTTP/s listeners for ELBs on you Environment configuration.